# bat file: variables have wrong value untill next execution of bat?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm reading a property from a .properties file (looks like: applocation=c:\x\y\z).
Using the line: `FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i "applocation" %1') DO set name=%%i`

%1 is the location of the .property file that I pass as an argument.

After setting the property I do:

> echo %applocation%

However the first time I execute the bat file it echoes the location from where I executed the bat file. Only after executing the bat file again from the same console window do I get the correct value.

This is quite peeving, especially since if I close the command window I have to do this all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely in a block of an if or another `for` there, I guess, such as this:

```
if foo (
    FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i "applocation" %1') DO set name=%%i
    echo %applocation%
)
```

This cannot work, as environment variables are expanded when *parsing* such a block, not when running it.

To use delayed expansion put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your batch file and then use

```
if foo (
    FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i "applocation" %1') DO set name=%%i
    echo !applocation!
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do the trick. The only thing missing is the endlocal.

Comment: @Jack, `endlocal` is implied at the end of a batch file. Remember that `setlocal` also set up a local environment. Any changes to environment variables will not persist after `endlocal` which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Won't work. See [Delayed Variable Expansion](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)

Comment: Had a look at it but: @echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i "applocation" %1') DO set applocation=!applocation!%%i
 echo %applocation%
ENDLOCAL never outputs anything?

Comment: You should use `echo !applocation!`